# How to get the edited text from itext in fabricjs

Tags: fabricjs

In my code I have put itext to get some numbers from the user.When the page is loaded itext contain a string 'value'.Then user can tap and change the value.I want this value.But I can't find any method to do so.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. please share the work you did and your errors in order to get a good answer www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: the .text property of your fabricjs object contains your input number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get your iText , text value by getting the **text** property of iText object, like this;  : `canvas.getActiveObject().text`

### Also, get event after edit text

You could use the `text:editing:exited` event, which is fired after the user has made the changes on the text and exit, like this:

```
canvas.on("text:editing:exited", function (e) {
    console.log('updated text:',e.target.text);    
    console.log("text:editing:exited");
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the text while editing? like  `onKeyUp` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use 'Text:changed' instead of 'text:editing:exited' to get text on every keystroke.